# Select based on unique pair of values

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, mariadb, having

i have a problem with a query that i must do in order to filter the data from a table.
Suppose to have the following table:

| id | col1 | col2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 12345 | 6789 |
| 2 | 6789 | 12345 |
| 3 | 3333 | 4213 |
| 4 | 12345 | 6789 |
| 5 | 6789 | 12345 |
| 6 | 1111 | 2222 |
| 7 | 12345 | 6789 |

if i execute the following query:

```
select * from  myTable
where (col1,col2) 
in(select col1, col2 from myTable group by col1,col2
having count(*) >= 4 and count(*) <= 100000 order by count(*) desc)
```

i would miss the unique pair "12345-6789" since it appear like that

| count | col1 | col2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 12345 | 6789 |
| 2 | 6789 | 12345 |

i've tried to search for a solution and i've found the following query:

```
SELECT CONCAT(LEAST(col1, col2), ',', GREATEST(col1, col2)) pair, 
       COUNT(*) count
FROM myTable
having count(*) >= 4 and count(*) <= 100000
GROUP BY pair
```

the problem with this query is that the outer select won't work cause the output is like:

| count | pair |
| --- | --- |
| 5 | 12345,6789 |

So my question is: is there a way to write the following query

select * from  myTable
where (col1,col2) in ( *unique pair of values from col1 e col2 that are counted independetly from the order in which they appear*)

so that i can have the following output:

| id | col1 | col2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 12345 | 6789 |
| 2 | 6789 | 12345 |
| 4 | 12345 | 6789 |
| 5 | 6789 | 12345 |
| 7 | 12345 | 6789 |

EDIT: the only thing i can think of is to split the process and get the first part of the result using the LEAST/GREATEST query, then in my code split the values and build 2 query (or 1 with a union)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the functions `LEAST()` and `GREATEST()` in the WHERE clause to create sorted pairs to compare with the pairs returned by the subquery:

```
SELECT *
FROM myTable
WHERE (LEAST(col1, col2), GREATEST(col1, col2)) IN (
  SELECT LEAST(col1, col2) c1, GREATEST(col1, col2) c2
  FROM myTable
  GROUP BY c1, c2
  HAVING COUNT(*) >= 4 and COUNT(*) <= 100000
);
```

This works in MariaDB and in MySql 5.5 and 5.6, but surprisingly [does not work in MySql 5.7+](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=9bef1e23a9f53481737ede7619b8fc58) (should be an unnoticed bug?).

If you change to a join instead of the operator `IN` then it works fine both in MySql and MariaDB:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM myTable t1 
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT LEAST(col1, col2) c1, GREATEST(col1, col2) c2
  FROM myTable
  GROUP BY c1, c2
  HAVING COUNT(*) >= 4 and COUNT(*) <= 100000
) t2 ON (t2.c1, t2.c2) = (LEAST(col1, col2), GREATEST(col1, col2));
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=e04414ebea4df72497d393fb78d1dc8f).

Comment: before today i didn't even know about LEAST/GREATEST function, i couldn't imagine that i could have used them also as condition. I Tried it and it works. Thank you very much